# Importing Sentinel-1 Image Collection to Google Earth Engine API

Tags: sentinel-1, google-earth-engine

I'm currently having an issue with trying to import the Sentinel-1 image collection into the [Earth Engine API](https://ee-api.appspot.com/). My script is as follows:

```js
var imgSentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1');
Map.centerObject(imgSentinel1, 3);
Map.addLayer(imgSentinel1);
```

The error outputted is as follows:

```js
Layer 1: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered:
  First image type: 2 bands ([HH, HV]).
Current image type: 2 bands ([VH, VV]).
      Image ID: S1A_EW_GRDH_1SDV_20141017T180916_20141017T181011_002873_0033FA_7339
Some bands might require explicit casts.
```

Since Sentinel-1 holds multiple bands, I try to filter the bands:

```js
Map.addLayer(imgSentinel1, {'bands':['HH, HV']});
```

The following is outputted:

```js
Layer 1: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered:
  First image type: 2 bands ([HH, HV]).
Current image type: 2 bands ([VH, VV]).
      Image ID: S1A_EW_GRDH_1SDV_20141013T234000_20141013T234103_002818_0032C9_90E3
Some bands might require explicit casts.
```

I've tried to change the bands (ex. 'HH', 'HV', 'VV', 'VH, VV'), but it would output:

```js
Layer 1: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered:
  First image type: 2 bands ([HH, HV]).
Current image type: 2 bands ([VH, VV]).
      Image ID: S1A_EW_GRDH_1SDV_20141013T234000_20141013T234103_002818_0032C9_90E3
Some bands might require explicit casts.
```

^ when 'HH', 'HV' or 'HH, HV' was inputted, and:

```js
Layer 1: Layer error: Image.visualize: No band named 'VV'. Available band names: [HH, HV].
```

^ when 'VV', 'VH', 'VH, VV' or 'VV, VH' was inputted for the bands. Other basic variables used for other satellite images like 'B1' also failed.

I wish to display any (and potentially all) bands that may be used for statistical analysis similar to displaying Landsat-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, it works for me :)

```
var p = function(image) { return image.log10().multiply(10)};

var pol = ['VV'];

var imgVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1').
 filter(ee.Filter.eq('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', pol)).
 filterMetadata('instrumentMode', 'equals', 'IW');

Map.addLayer(imgVV),
Map.setCenter(-119.84, 37.83, 8);
```

Comment: filter(ee.Filter.eq('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', pol)).

That was what I was looking for, though someone else already helped me out on the EE group. Thanks though!

Comment: Hi, is there a chance you could explain what the issue was, and how this code solves it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The original issue is that the 'transmitterReceiverPolarisation' metadata field is a list.

The fix shown above only retrieves instances when there is a single polarization included. This would have a metadata field of `['HH']` (for example).

Sentinel-1 may have one or two polarizations.  The GEE Guide related to Sentinel-1 Algorithms shows that the metadata can be `['VV'], ['HH'], ['VV', 'VH'], or ['HH', 'HV']`.

This Guide shows that the filter should be general

```
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
```